На ubuntu 22.04 возникает ошибка при отправке https запросов приложением qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::startServerEncryption: TLS initialization failed
В приложении на С++ собранном на qt 5.12.3 в ubuntu при отправке https запросов возникает ошибка qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::startServerEncryption: TLS initialization failed
В ubuntu на котором было собрано приложение версия библиотеки openssl 1.0, пробовал обновлять до 1.1 и 3.0, при повторных сборках ошибка не ушла.
На qt-форуме находил что нужно добавить в систему сборки TLS  плагин:
TLS/
libqcertonlybackend.so
libqopensslbackend.so
libqcertonlybackend.debug
libqopensslbackend.debug

А вот куда его добавить и где скачать не нашел...
Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, помогите пожалуйста)
